# Why is vpython unable to display multiple spheres in some circumstances?

Tags: python, 3d, vpython, 3d-modelling

I am attempting to write a model for flock mentality - 'boids' - in Python. I am having a problem with the vpython 3d modelling, as it appears to be unable to display multiple spheres at once unless they are next to each other in the code.

The bare bones of the relevant part of my code is:

```
    def uniform_distr(x1, x2):
        x1, x2 = float(x1), float(x2)
        return x1 + random() * (x2 - x1)

    def random_position_vector():
        return vector(uniform_distr(-1, 1), uniform_distr(-1, 1), uniform_distr(-1, 1))

    def random_unit_vector():
        return norm(vector(random(), random(), random()))


    class Boid:
        def __init__(self,
                     initial_velocity = random_unit_vector(),
                     initial_position = random_position_vector()):

            self.velocity = initial_velocity

            self.position = initial_position

            self.model = sphere(pos = self.position, radius = 0.05, color = color.red,
                                    make_trail = False)


    boid_list = [Boid(), Boid(), Boid()]
```

I would like this to display three randomly placed spheres, but I only get one. I can get three spheres by running:

```
Ball1 = sphere(pos = vector(1,0,0), radius = 0.05)
Ball2 = sphere(pos = vector(0,1,0), radius = 0.05)
Ball3 = sphere(pos = vector(0,0,1), radius = 0.05)
```

What is the problem that is causing this? I have read through a lot of documentation, but I can't see why there is only one showing in the previous code!

Answer (score 0):

Please provide a small but working program. I don't know what environment your're using, but I'm assuming you're using VPython 7 (Jupyter notebook? Spyder?) and that you preface your code with

from vpython import *
from random import *

I constructed a program from these lines followed by your first code followed by the 3 sphere statements, and I see 3 white spheres and 1 red sphere.

For VPython questions it's better to post to the VPython forum, where there are many more VPython users who will see your question than if you post to stackoverflow:

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups&hl=en#!forum/vpython-users

Comment: I am using Pycharm - yes I prefaced it with this.

The top code is meant to provide three spheres, as the Boid() class gets called three times. The bottom (separate code) is meant to provide three spheres.

My question is why the top code can only show one sphere at a time.

Comment: I don't fully understand why it causes a problem, but it looks quite odd to me to have 2 arguments for the __init__ function, but no arguments are supplied in creating the class instances. Remove those arguments from __init__ and just use self.position = random_position_vector() and self.velocity = random_unit_vector(). This seems to be a Python issue, not a VPython issue. If you insert a print statement in your current code you'll see that three spheres are indeed created, but all with the same position. Incidentally, Note that the VPython vector class has a function vector.random()

Comment: I had used the args in init() for when I want to create Boid instances with specific position and velocity instead of random - this is one of the ideas I have for the future. Thanks for the tip with print(), I hadn't done that!